# What do you call the dots that show the number of images on the home page of a site and let you switch between them?

Tags: website-design

I've seen this before on a lot of websites and I really like it. I would really like to put it on my website, what is this slideshow looking thing called and how do you do this?

Circled in red.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A set of images on a home page that rotate, or allow the user to page between them is called a "carousel".   The dots are called "carousel-indicators".

Any time that I'm asked about carousels on web pages give this advice: [don't use them](https://conversionxl.com/blog/dont-use-automatic-image-sliders-or-carousels/).

Comment: `I'm asked about carousels on web pages give this advice: don't use them.` Tell people / customers is the easy part, getting them to understand and not use a slider is a whole different ball game.

Comment: See http://shouldiuseacarousel.com/ for an ironic answer to this question.